# Getting LineEdit.text() from another imported file

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using `python2.7` with `pyqt 4.10` and I have two py files

the first one called `Warehouse.py` that contains `class Ui_mainWindow(object):` and in it there is a function `def setupUi(self, mainWindow):` inside of it there is the creation of the widget `lineEdit`

now in the 2nd file, I need to call the text within this widget, I've used this code:

```
    import Warehouse
    user1 = Ui_mainWindow.setupUi().lineEdit.text()
```

So, it returns me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\townoftech-warehouse\item_entry.py", line 109, in item_in
    user1 = Ui_mainWindow.setupUi().lineEdit.text()
NameError: global name 'Ui_mainWindow' is not defined
```

Comment: you mispelled the class name. You called it Ui_mainWindo... should be Ui_mainWindow

Comment: Yes, thank you but it didn't work after recorrecting it, it gave me this error:`NameError: global name 'Ui_mainWindow' is not defined`

Comment: You're wrong if you're thinking that a program is a file set. A program is a set of elements such as functions, classes, etc. that interact and implement the logic, so what you ask is incorrect. You have to create an object of the Ui_mainWindow class along with a QMainWindow and use setupUi() to fill in the widget, and then there will be QLineEdit, and you can use it recently.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi: how is your second file called from the fiirst file, or the other way around? We need more insigth to your code to help you. Furthermore setupUi() is a function to create the `lineEdit`, not an object under the class to provide `lineEdit` as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot import 2 files to each other.. just take the classes and method from one file and used in the other files so I didn't need to import!